# How can I convince my boss that we need better machines?

Tags: management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I request new equipment for the office?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6630/how-do-i-request-new-equipment-for-the-office)

My boss strongly feels that if we keep the machines clean which to him means: not installing any unnecessary programs and formatting the computer routinely, there is no need to purchase a new machine at least until it has been used for ten years.

I tried to tell him that slow machines really hinder productivity and software gets heavier over time, but he would reiterate his argument.

What is a good way to convince my boss to buy us a new machine?

Comment: Are you looking for technical data on how a faster computer would help? Or looking for a way to present this to your boss and convince him of your side of the debate.

Comment: @ryadavilli I'm not 100% sure what you mean by technical data here, but I'm mostly looking for the latter.

Comment: Instead of shopping for new machines, I think you need to shop for a new boss. This guy is cutting corners everywhere.

Comment: @DA. Of course he's cutting corners, it's a small company. They're not all Microsofts where a new workstation is not even a measurable blip on the monthly turnover. Likely as not, new high-end developer workstations would be a considerable investment for this company. The point is, how to make the case that the investment is worth it.

Comment: @pap: make the point that a new high-end developer workstation might be a considerable investment, but a new developer will be a *really* considerable investment.

Comment: Very related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/93983/why-dont-all-companies-buy-developers-the-best-hardware

Comment: @Carson63000 Exactly!

Comment: If a new high-end desktop would improve your performance; why don't you pay for it?  You'd complete your work in significantly less time, outshine your coworkers, and out any performance evaluations.

Comment: This is a different question than was linked.

Comment: @pap any person starting a software business and not taking into account basic supplies such as hardware isn't someone I'd want running a business.

Comment: @DA. Well and good, but the world isn't perfect and if we were to apply such standards there wouldn't be many start-ups around. I get the sense that you've never started a business or worked in a start-up, but I can tell you that having the latest workstations usually take a back-seat to stuff like making payroll and paying office rent. Especially when, like in this case, the boss (owner?) thinks the current tools are sufficient. The point I'm making is that rather than whining like an entitled brat, you need to make a rational case for it, ROI. Only a developer thinks it's self-evident.

Comment: Voting to re-open. How to justify investments in tools differs between small/start-up companies and large ones are different cases and I think the "small business" aspect makes this a valid question.

Comment: @pap there's obviously a lot we don't know about the situation. This doesn't sound like a young tech in a garage starting the next facebook, though. Even they wouldn't be trying to get work done on a 10 year old machine. You painting it as 'whining like an entitled brat' is juvenile. Tools are required to perform work and companies that don't provide adequate tools is typically a sign of mismanagement.

Comment: And while there's certainly different criteria based on the size of the company, I've seen this same behavior in huge organizations as well...a complete lack of proper management of hardware tools. It's silly, but common. (It usually stems from people that don't have to use the tools making the decisions as to what tools to provide.)

Comment: ASk for maximum RAM to utilize it the best - you might be VERY surprised.

Comment: I am also voting to reopen this one as I feel the question and answers on the linked question focus primarily on office furniture, while this one specifically focuses on computers. Also, I like the accepted answer to this one :)

Comment: Ah well, at my company we have to buy our own machines.  At least we get to have this argument with ourselves :/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Everything is about Money. So you need to show that the machines will pay for themselves better then what you currently have.

One way to do this is to determine the average spent per employee on their machine compiling code, **AND** other functions which take time.

Do it for a week or two (or a month), get a report from each engineer of the amount of time involved. Then work that amount of time out for the year and equate it to lost productivity.

**Example:** Let's say each engineer compiles their code 10 times a day. So you have lost 20-30 minutes per engineer a day. Let's pick the average and say 25 minutes per engineer.

That works out to 4.5 days a year per engineer is lost productivity. For 6 engineers that is 27 days of productivity lost.

Comment: +1, good answer. Like any investment, you need to present a real ROI estimation. What does it cost you to use (and maintain!) these old machines versus how much would it cost to buy new ones. And don't forget to include **all** costs associated. If you need to, for instance, reformat, reinstall and set up the dev environment on your machines every month, then you need to include the time spent on that.

Comment: It's not that simple. There are generally different budgets for capital expenditure and operating expenditure and it's often easier to lose money in the latter than the former.

Comment: @pdr excellent point.

Comment: @pdr It's a 6-person company. While amortized vs direct costs will have some impact on tax-liability, I doubt their budgeting and bookkeeping is complex enough that you can "lose" stuff in one or the other. Plus, at that size cash-flow tend to be more important than quarterly EBIT. You're thinking "large company" style.

Comment: It is not always that easy, your boss can retort that you can do something while compiling like answering to mail, reviewing some documentation, etc. Although it is extremely inefficient every 10 minutes, it is doable.

Comment: @pap: Not really. Even given those conditions (which localizes the question a lot), the wages will have already been agreed for the year, it's a sunk cost. New hardware will have to come from somewhere else, and that may well be even more difficult to justify in a small company than a large one. ie. There may be no capex budget, as such, it might need justifying case-by-case. It is easier for a manager to say "screw it, I'll take the loss of productivity," if he still thinks the product will be delivered on time.

Comment: I would be wary of the argument that faster compile times will automatically lead to greater productivity, because it is exactly the same argument used to justify blocking websites and forbidding breaks in order to force employees to "work" every minute of the day. For all you know, the time taken to compile might be giving your brain enough rest to work more efficiently on the next task.

Comment: @pdr I agree this question is more localized, but still very valid. How to justify investments in tools differs between small/start-up companies and large ones. In this case, talking about a "manager" becomes a bit absurd since the "manager" is likely the CEO, owner and founder as well. It's essentially **his** money we're talking about.

Answer (score 9):

Wow, I thought I was crazy sticking with a 2005 PC..

In addition to the fine answer by Simon, I would like to add my own points.

With such an old machine, **Repair costs** are likely to be much higher, especially compared to repair under warranty. You have not given any specifics, but if you have situations or data regarding this, you can use that to further your case.

Newer Machines and LCD monitors might consume lower **power**, low enough to be significant over 3-5 years.

Additionally, when presenting your case, take a mid-range machine as the ideal case, a high-end one might be going into diminishing returns area for a small company.

Comment: Good points. I'd also add that if you are showing a mid-range machine, to show a top end machine (which he won't buy) so as to make the mid-range look more economical. I got that trick from Dan Ariely. http://danariely.com

Answer (score 6):

Be careful how you try to present any ROI argument. There are a lot of purchases that could be made to help the bottom line over time, but are no good right now if your company doesn't have the cash or if venture capital is restricted. You may be able to prevent wasting a certain amount of time per day/per programmer, but there are other factors:

1. Does your boss expect you to just work longer hours without extra pay because you're on salary?
2. You boss thinks each programmer already has several minutes of unproductive time, so you might as well be compiling at the same time.
3. Your company can't find any more billable hours or additional work to justify the time savings. More productive hours may not directly create revenue.
4. Projects are not behind, so why bother saving the extra time? (Would be hard to believe.).

Part of me thinks you're arguing with an idiot or someone who has been beaten up too often and has developed penny wise and pound foolish thinking. I don't agree with the arguments I presented nor do I know if your boss thinks this way.

The slow computers are probably another symptom about the problems with working for this company. Your boss is giving the impression he just doesn't care to try and make employees happy. It's not all about money. There are other 'perks' he could offer that don't require as much company cash (e.g. flex-time, telecommute, free muffins on Tuesday, allow you to try and find other solutions/buy just one machine for compiling.).

Answer (score -2):

In all likelihood, you can't. Sorry, there it is.

The problem is departmentalization: beancounter 1 is responsible for office arrangement, beancounter 2 for machines, beancounter 3 for programmer's productivity and project.

BC 1 and 2 do not care the least bit about BC 3's interests.

Read good discussion how noise and open space ruin team productivity in Peopleware (deMarco) IIRC and McConnell's books. Both are top of the line experts on sw development processes, not to mention other people like Paul Graham, all oppose noisy environments like open space and then... nothing happens. It all stays the same. The problem is that assessing programmer productivity is loaded with lots of difficulties or risks, while beancounting on $100 on hard drive or office arrangement is easy, so beancounters go with the latter option. Remember: people do not go for profitable options, but for EASY ones!

I'm typing this on laptop with mechanical drive even though this kills productivity given our sw dev environment. Trying to phrase this in economics of entire company falls on deaf ears.

UPDATE:

OK scratch the 3 beancounters, roll them all into 1, namely the boss in question. That still does not change the basic problem I described: assessing impact of old machines on programmer productivity is hard, bc assessing productivity of programmers as such is hard. The losses in employee time given the old machines in all likelihood are much bigger than the cost of the new equipment. But evaluating the cost of the former is easy vs evaluating the latter is hard, so your boss does the former.

All you could do I think is simple calculation like:

compilation done n times on average each day * number of employees doing compilation * employee wage per compilation instance time = $X.

If you tried to put this in numerical terms, maybe it will work - but even then I think it won't, as such people typically have vain hope that it will work well enough as it is and that those other losses are not real since evaluating those losses is debatable and hard.

That's your best chance although I'm afraid the boss response will be "don't make programming errors and reduce the number of compilations!".

Comment: Question says "(6 employees)" and you think there are three beancounters?

Comment: @AakashM: indeed. The issue here is surely not departmentalization of bean counters, but the fact that the guy counting the beans sees them as *his* beans. Small company, I'm assuming the boss is the owner, any new computer purchase is going to feel like *him* buying a new computer for *you*. Not like the company making a necessary business purchase to improve productivity.