# How do I request for additional softwares for development?

Tags: project-management, developer, software

I'm working as Senior Software Developer and my company mainly deals in financial services sector. That's why high level security is implemented in our system and we cannot install any software (whether licensed or free) without manager's permission. There are some tool's to speed up the development like Clipx, LinqPad etc. and I want to install those in my office machine. How do I convince my project manager to give me the permission to install these software?

--

Comment: Are you allowed to run the software you compile on your own machine

Comment: I take it as a personal challenge when admin restricts some thing:D but dont do that just shoot a mail requesting SW listing all pros and savings in hours.Management is all concerned about money and efficency.

Comment: I assume you already tried asking and explained the benefit?

Comment: Related: [How do I request new equipment for the office?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6630)

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple: you need to clearly articulate what the benefit of those tools. what is the cost saving if you were to "vet" and install those tools as opposed to just not use it. if the delta is high enough your **manager** will pay attention.