# How concerned about expensing the business should I be?

Tags: new-hires, expenses

I've just started a new job, and as part of setting up my workstation I requested a new, larger mouse - as I've had experience with hand cramps with the standard small mouses that are everywhere.

We looked at the existing spare mice, and there were none suitable there - so my manager asked me to find the mouse that I want and send it to him.

I've done so - but the mouse is the upper end of the price range for computer mice ($100+ - local currency - not the US) - the Logitech MX series. It's not like I've gone out and looked for the most expensive mouse - I've had experience with the brand and I know that these work for me. That said, I'm sure I could shop around more and find a cheaper mouse, saving say $50.

It all seems a bit absurd worrying about what's less than a day's pay difference - but I'm primarily concerned about the impression I might make - as a prima dona.

Comment: I requested a 2800,- Euro macbook on my first day. I'd say go ahead and indeed, ask.

Comment: That sort of money is nothing compared to the costs the company could face if you damage your wrist because of your work station. I'd be astonished if they would worry about this. Definitely not prima donna to look after your health.

Answer (score 6):

If this rodent is really that much better (I hate mice and use a trackball instead), tell your manager why and let him decide it he can justify the cost. In my own company, it isn't hard to justify reasonable investments in ergonomics; they don't want emoloyees slowed down by RSI.

Comment: I like using a large mouse as well.  I got a nice Logitech for less than $75 - company paid.  We have a soft limit of $75 for misc stuff.  Anything over that needs more approval, so it was ok.

Comment: Another trackball user here. I've gotten trackballs at my last two jobs with no problems or real fanfare at all. Now a days I think companies are used to dealing with peoples different needs and generally have a variety of things available. Ergo/Non-ergo keyboards. Various mice. Trackballs. Monitor stands. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm primarily concerned about the impression I might make - as a prima dona.

Being marked as a prima donna has much more to do with attitude than making requests, especially if those requests are entirely reasonable or common. You can even make uncommon requests as long as you word it well and make sure it's a request not a demand. When requesting stuff at work, the key point is to simply ask for something while outlining the costs and benefits and not appearing *entitled*. The way you do the latter is by making it clear that you won't throw a fit if the answer is no, whether by explicitly saying so ("*If it isn't possible I'll bring my own in.*") or by outlining alternatives ("*I could also use X but it would be less convenient*").

Beyond that, strategies for making equipment requests can be found here: [How do I request new equipment for the office?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6630/how-do-i-request-new-equipment-for-the-office)

Answer (score 0):

100 Bucks is complete chump change when avoiding RSI for someone, so your manager will most likely have no problem with that.

You brought the best argument for that yourself: You're a presumably nicely paid employee, and the employer wants to get the most out of the time they're paying you for, so 100 bucks for a mouse that will help you do that and additionally help you avoid RSI (which can be costly for the employer due to mandatory slowdown in the healing period and even potential absence) is well worth it in terms of a business expense.

If your employer has a history of quibbling over very minor expenses like this, it may be worth it for your standing in the company and for your own sanity to just pay it yourself and not expense it. But thats up to you. Like you said, thats less then a day's pay, so its not that big of a deal in any case.

Answer (score -6):

$99 retail is a lot for a mouse.  I have one and it is nice but I am a gamer.  That is a gaming level mouse that does not even do that well on regular mouse pad.  On my main PC I have regular mouse I got for $20.  When I do development work on my gamer I have to turn the sensitivity down.

A days pay is a relatively large amount of money.

Kensington has a large mouse for $20.  You don't need a gaming mouse unless you are a game developer.

What if there are 10 people in the department that see a flashy gaming mouse and all decide they get hand fatigue also.  Look around at the level of hardware.  If they are buying nice PCs and nice monitors that $99 might not be pushing it.  It they have old PCs and old monitors and stuff does not get replaced until it dies then $99 for a mouse is pushing it.

Coming in at $40 with regular basic looking but large mouse is much different profile.

I tore a rotator cuff and paid for gaming left handed mouse for work. I showed it to my boss and informed him I would be taking it back when my rotator cuff healed.

Comment: $99 for an ergonomically matched mouse that prevents RSI (and potential loss of time) is not a lot for a mouse in a company that cares about that kind of stuff

Comment: 100 bucks is chump change for increasing performance and avoiding RSI.