# What to do when your employer won’t upgrade inadequate computers

Tags: computer-science

I work in advertising for a multimillion dollar company. We have 2018 Mac Minis that shut down frequently. We have to work over to meet deadlines because of how poorly they perform. We have asked for upgrades and they don’t want to spend the money. The overtime pay alone would pay for upgrades! What can we do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I request new equipment for the office?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6630/how-do-i-request-new-equipment-for-the-office)

Comment: A computer should not "shut down". That sounds like a mechanical/electrical/operating system failure, not a "too slow" computer. They worked in 2018, didn't they? It's not like we reinvented advertising since then. Have you contacted your IT support or Apple support? What did they say what the problem is?

Comment: Follow up question: where do you live? Is not doing overtime an option?

Answer (score 6):

1. Make a business case (with actual numbers) that quantifies over time and productivity savings in $, investment required and calculates the break even point and the ROI over the projected lifetime of the PC (4 years is about standard)
2. Augment this with some research studies like this one https://news.microsoft.com/en-nz/2018/10/16/true-cost-of-not-replacing-computers-revealed-in-microsoft-study-more-than-4000-each/
3. Run this by your manager first, to make sure they are ok with it and can provide feedback.
4. The run it by the IT department.
5. If you have a compelling case and they still not going for it your options are a) Elevate to senior management, b) make your peace with it, c) find a new job